# Error while installing rb-appscript gem

Tags: rubygems, rb-appscript

I want to create a rails app using Test-Driven Development (TDD), so i wrote

```
rails new myproject -T
```

then I added these lines of code  in the gemfile

```
group :test, :development do
    gem 'turn'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem 'growl_notify'
end
```

so i tried to install the bundle but i got this error while bundling

```
Installing rb-appscript (0.6.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
extconf.rb:44: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
create /var/lib/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/src/osx_ruby.h ...
create /var/lib/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/src/osx_intern.h ...
creating Makefile

make
Makefile:226: warning: overriding commands for target `/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/lib'
Makefile:224: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/lib'
compiling src/rbae.c
src/rbae.c:13:27: fatal error: Carbon/Carbon.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [rbae.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/./gem_make.out
An error occured while installing rb-appscript (0.6.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rb-appscript -v '0.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

so i tried to install the gem manually

```
gem install rb-appscript -v '0.6.1'
```

i got this similar error too

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rb-appscript:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb
extconf.rb:44: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
create /var/lib/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/src/osx_ruby.h ...
create /var/lib/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/src/osx_intern.h ...
creating Makefile

make
Makefile:226: warning: overriding commands for target `/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/lib'
Makefile:224: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/lib'
compiling src/rbae.c
src/rbae.c:13:27: fatal error: Carbon/Carbon.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [rbae.o] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/./gem_make.out
```

so any Suggestions what can I do now ?

Comment: What OS version are you using?

Comment: Also from rb-appscript's site: *"Please note that appscript is no longer developed or supported, and its use is not recommended for new projects."*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Growl is for Mac OS X only, instead of `growl_notify` you probably want:

```
gem 'libnotify'
```

Read more in the [Guard readme](https://github.com/guard/guard/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Getting a same issue for Mac OS X Yosemite for me though.